# Has carbon dating indicated that live humans are 4000 years old?

Tags: biology, chemistry, radiation, archeology

A friend of mine told my wife that carbon dating is unreliable because it has been performed on live humans and indicated that the test subject(s) are 4000 years old.

Is there any truth to this claim? I'm having a hard time finding anything about it.

Comment: You can't do carbon dating on living tissue... Because of respiration, the C-14 is constantly being replaced thus invalidating any results.

Comment: Maybe you mean "contemporary" and not "live" humans?

Comment: @Skliwz I can only guess at what she actually said/meant. Would changing the statement to "comtemporary" make it any more truthful?

Comment: Most dating used to determine age for bones/artifacts/etc that are expected to be over 50k years is done through means other than carbon-dating like Thermoluminescence, Tephrochronology, Magnetostratigraphy, etc.  Typically several forms of analysis are used on the objects and surrounding sediment in order to get multiple confirmations and greater accuracy.  I know this doesn't directly address carbon-dating which is why I am supplying it as a comment

Comment: Performing carbon dating on live humans also sounds *painful*.

Comment: @Shadur - I would suggest "living", if you're referring to people who are currently alive, or "contemporary" for people who died recently.

Comment: @Sklivvz I've heard the "live humans" claim before, in the context of young-earth creationists trying to prove our methods of measuring fossil age are completely useless and/or actually show fossils are only a thousand or so years old (which wouldn't make sense anyway based on the valid range from SeanDuggan's answer..)

Comment: @Izkata right on the nose.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

[The use of Carbon-14 for dating](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiocarbon_dating) is not completely precise. In general, 500 years is the minimum and 50,000 years is the maximum due to the need to calibrate for background C-14 levels, and to have sufficient breakdown to establish the half-life proportions but not so much that the sample is too small to measure.

That said, [they're using Carbon-14 dating on recent human remains in forensic science](http://nij.gov/journals/269/pages/carbon-dating.aspx) , although the technique works best on bodies around the 1940s to 1960s due to the increased presence of C-14 due to atomic bomb testing. Currently, the atmospheric levels of C-14 are dropping again, so the method will be less feasible for people deceased after that point.

Given the difficulty of dating samples less than 500 years old, I could readily see your friend, or the person who gave him that information, latching on to the idea of less aged items being hard to date and the actual figure involved getting enlarged with the telling.

Comment: Correct. For other time ranges, you'd have to use [another](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiometric_dating#Modern_dating_methods) isotope.

Comment: To sum it up, carbon dating is fairly reliable when used to determine the age of *formerly living organic material that died between 500 and 50000 years ago*, and becomes drastically less useful for anything outside those parameters.

Comment: @Shadur Not directly relevant to this question I would add the caveat that the organsism used to be airbreathing, and did not feed on waterbreathers to a large extent.

Comment: Must one  be sure at first that the item is more than 500 years old before using C14 dating ? (that would means that at least 2 dating methods must be used)

Comment: @Emmanuel:
I'm not an expert, but I think it would just come out as "within 500 years old". But yes, for any form of destructive testing, such as radiocardon dating, they usually use other methods to gauge the age of the artifact or specimen.

Comment: @SeanDuggan http://www.icr.org/article/myths-regarding-radiocarbon-dating/  Myth number 3 is most likely where OP's question came from, as i have heard this alot in church circles, while the creation institute would obviously be biased, they actually explain correctly that it is a myth to assume because some living creatures date to be thousands of years old, that it is proof to discard carbon dating.

Answer (score 5):

A "live human" would [by definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiocarbon_dating#Principles) have an age of 0 on the carbon dating scale, since the carbon in the live human is in active exchange with the environment, and hence the C14:C12 ratio would be identical to the baseline. Carbon dating scales measure the changes in this ratio after death of the organism.

This will be true even if humans somehow are capable of actively removing C14 from their bodies, the baseline would be set to that of a live human. One of the first steps in measurement of radiocarbon age is to [find a valid baseline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiocarbon_dating#cite_note-:0-13), usually from measuring a living organism. One of the comments above is especially relevant in this aspect:

> Not directly relevant to this question I would add the caveat that the organsism used to be airbreathing, and did not feed on waterbreathers to a large extent.

Since waterbreathing organisms contain different ratios of C14:C12, the baseline would have to be adjusted, if you are measuring C14 in a mummified fish, for example, the first step would be normalising the C14 ratios to a recently dead (fresh) fish. [This link](http://sciencenordic.com/fish-corrupt-carbon-14-dating) explains why this has to be done:

> Hard water contains high levels of calcium carbonate. Carbonate contains carbon, including carbon-14. However, depending on ocean water circulation, fish and other living creatures can incorporate 'older' carbonate (with less carbon-14) into their bodies. When these organisms die and fossilise, they appear to be much older than they actually are.

[This book](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=roEsBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA4&lpg=PA4&dq=14c%20normalisation&source=bl&ots=AUG0lwrdLt&sig=zzLJBCTtmN-xLICnyiXok25iPII&hl=en&sa=X&ei=1HaNVPn8JNGWavT9gsAH&ved=0CDkQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=14c%20normalisation&f=false) about radiocarbon dating of the Iceman also used a set of standards (wood samples), it having already been shown that humans and trees have comparable C14 ratios when alive.

Therefore, saying that a human was measured to have an age of 4000 using carbon dating would be equivalent to saying that you placed a thermometer into a bowl of melting ice and measured the temperature to be 50 degrees Celsius: the measurement instrument is incorrectly calibrated, or otherwise nonfunctional.

Comment: Added additional citations, especially regarding the fish claim.